# Variant of the knapsack

Tags: c++, algorithm, knapsack-problem

Similarly to the original problem, I am given some items(with weight and value) and should fill the knapsack to get maximal total value. However, in this version of the algorithm, I am provided with unlimited number of copies of each item. Could you suggest some ideas/pseudocode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the unbounded knapsack problem, and there are lots of links out there.
Some may include:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Unbounded_knapsack_problem
- http://www.csegeek.com/csegeek/view/tutorials/algorithms/dynamic_prog/dp_part7.php
- http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/323/Syllabus/DynProg/knapsack2.html